# How do I create versions of updates at redshift

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I'm working in a feature and i need to store versions of an attribute update.

I'm using a redshift.

Someone help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In this specific case. I'll need to create a versions of data. For example. 

My table: cars -> color: 'blue'

When it occurs an update to color 'red'. I need to create a version of old state.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to persist previous/old versions of a row when you make changes like what temporal tables do? If so, and given Redshift is a DW, you're dealing with type 2 "slowly" changing dimensions?

There's no native support for that in Redshift but is easy enough to implement on your own. You can pay the cost on write, read or periodic maintenance depending on your environment. E.g. Implement your table with a timestamp column that's auto populated. SELECTs will retrieve unique rows using the primary key and latest version using MAX of the timestamp. This will be more expensive on reads as your table gets large.

You can also insert the previous row into a history table during write operations. That way, queries to your current table always has the latest values but your writes will be more expensive.

Search SO or just google the subject, LOTS of examples and their associated pros/cons.